# CitrusFramework CustomAction did not failed testcase in Test Results

Tags: junit, junit4, citrus-framework

Actually all suggested code from @Christoph is not give answer
Somehow explanations from Christoph is valid in before test scenario but not in after test

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="correlationId")
    public String getCorrelationId() {
        return RandomNumberFunction.getRandomNumber(48, false);
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("correlationId")
    public SequenceAfterTest afterTest() {
        return new KrampCitrusTestRunnerAfterTestSupport();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("correlationId")
    public SequenceBeforeTest  beforeTest() {
        return new KrampCitrusTestRunnerBeforeTestSupport();
     }
    }
```

after test class

```
    public class KrampCitrusTestRunnerAfterTestSupport
        extends TestRunnerAfterTestSupport {


    @Override
    public void afterTest(TestRunner runner) {

         runner.echo("This action should be executed after each test");
         runner.fail("message");
      }
    }
```

So this configuration produce following - pls notice its report for TEST SUCESS?!?!

```
14:19:50,900 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,901 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,903 WARN       citrus.TestCase| After test failed with errors
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:236)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.DefaultTestRunner.run(DefaultTestRunner.java:198)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.DefaultTestRunner.fail(DefaultTestRunner.java:265)
    at com.kramp.eai.test.common.iibexception.KrampCitrusTestRunnerAfterTestSupport.afterTest(KrampCitrusTestRunnerAfterTestSupport.java:45)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.TestRunnerAfterTestSupport.doExecute(TestRunnerAfterTestSupport.java:48)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.afterTest(TestCase.java:203)....
    Caused by: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: message
at com.consol.citrus.actions.FailAction.doExecute(FailAction.java:40)
at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:229)
... 31 more
14:19:50,917 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,917 INFO         citrus.Citrus| -----------------------------------
 -------------------------------------
14:19:50,917 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| AFTER TEST SUITE: SUCCESS
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| -----------------------------------
-------------------------------------
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| -----------------------------------
-------------------------------------
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| CITRUS TEST RESULTS
14:19:50,918 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,924 INFO         citrus.Citrus|  TC12: CDM............................... SUCCESS
14:19:50,924 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:19:50,924 INFO         citrus.Citrus| TOTAL: 1
14:19:50,924 INFO         citrus.Citrus| FAILED:    0 (0.0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are in the after test phase of JUnit or TestNG. This is technically no more part of the Citrus test. You should be using *AfterTestSupport classes in Citrus as described here: http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/test-suite.html#after-test. Only then you have access to test variables and test boundaries in Citrus.

Comment: Still no good `@Override
 public void afterTest(TestRunner runner) {    FailAction action = new FailAction();
         action.setMessage("ERROR");
         runner.run(action); } ` I get this in report INFO  nnerAfterTestSupport, event name: output
WARN       citrus.TestCase| After test failed with errors
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed citrus.Citrus| AFTER TEST SUITE: SUCCESS
citrus.Citrus| 
citrus.Citrus| CITRUS TEST RESULTS
FlowTestCase.flowTestItemUpdateMessage  SUCCESS

Comment: You must add the AfterTestSupport class to the Spring application context either using XML bean definition in citrus-context.xml

    `<bean id="afterTestRunner" class="com.company.MyAfterTestSupport"/>`

Or via Java Spring bean config

    `@Bean
    public SequenceAfterTest afterTest() {
        return new MyAfterTestSupport();
    }`